# Is it possible to a single void method's body with mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

I want to override the implementation of a single void method of a class using Mockito. The other methods should be stubbed.

I have tried something like this, but it does not compile since `java.lang.Void != void`:

```
MyObj obj = mock(MyObj.class);
doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
        return null;
    }
}).when(obj.myMethod(any(String.class)));
```

Is there no "doInvoke" or something like that?

Must I resort to standard Java class extend-and-override before mocking the extended class?

Comment: Given that it's not going to return anything, what do you want your custom call to do?

Comment: Set a variable or two based on the input (actually the method has input variables), which I later will inspect. I know I can accomplish the same with verify() but I'd like to have options where I can use assert() instead, for cleaner code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#do_family_methods_stubs):

> Stubbing voids requires different approach from when(Object) because the compiler does not like void methods inside brackets...
>
> `doThrow(Throwable)` replaces the `stubVoid(Object)` method for stubbing voids. The main reason is improved readability and consistency with the family of `doAnswer()` methods.
>
> You can use `doThrow()`, `doAnswer()`, `doNothing()`, `doReturn()` and `doCallRealMethod()` in place of the corresponding call with when(), for any method. It is necessary when you
>
> - stub void methods
> - stub methods on spy objects (see below)
> - stub the same method more than once, to change the behaviour of a mock in the middle of a test.
>
> but you may prefer to use these methods in place of the alternative with when(), for all of your stubbing calls.

So it sounds like you just want:

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
        return null;
    }
}).when(obj).myMethod(any(String.class));
```